# Create a bound field alias in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a javascript object, properties of which I am trying to display and edit using templates. Here's a simple illustration:

```
    <div ng-init="friends = [
            {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
            {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
            {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
            {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
            {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
            {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
            {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
            {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
            {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
            {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
        ]" />

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="render">
        <span>{{data}}</span>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="render">
        <span title="some fancy renderer">{{data}}</span>
    </script>

    <p ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="data in [friend.name]" ng-include="'render'"></span>, 
        <span ng-repeat="data in [friend.age]" ng-include="'render'"></span>
        <span ng-repeat="data in [friend.gender]" ng-include="'render'"></span>
    </p>
```

What I am trying to do is pass the piece I want to render inside `data` variable. I know `ng-repeat` directive works here to do what I want, but I think I am doing it wrong. There's got to be a simpler way to achieve the same goal

Another thing I am trying to achieve here is to make field bind, so that if that was an `<input ng-model="data" />`, actual field was modified

**EDIT:** For those of you who are interested, this solution worked, and provided 2-way bind as well:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="render">
    <input ng-model="d.o[d.f]" />
</script>

<p ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <span ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="d={o:friend, f:'name'}" ng-include="'render'">
    </span>
    <span ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="d={o:friend, f:'age'}" ng-include="'render'">
    </span>
    <span ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="d={o:friend, f:'gender'}" ng-include="'render'">
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you need to write a directive.
ng-repeat "works" because it created a new $scope.
Or you can create an empty controller that will create a scope

```
  <p ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-controller="ctrl" onload="data =friend.name" ng-include="'render'"></span>, 
        <span  ng-controller="ctrl" onload="data =friend.age" ng-include="'render'"></span>
        <span ng-controller="ctrl" onload="data =friend.gender" ng-include="'render'"></span>
    </p>
```

controller :

```
function ctrl(){}
```

> Another thing I am treying to achieve here is to make field bund, so
>   that if that was an , actual field was
>   modified

Not sure i understand what you mean here.

Comment: Sorry for multiple typos... What I wanted to do is to make sure that changing the `data` variable would also change the corresponding field, sich as `friend.age`, etc